# How to call google map api using swift 4?

Tags: swift, google-api

My issue is a, I need only restaurant, bar using google API.

If you need code i'm send you.

this is my base `url:- "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/"`

```
nearbyURLFragment :- let nearbyURLFragment = "nearbysearch/json?key=%@&location=%f,%f&rankby=distance&type=restaurant,bar"
```

a single type of proper working.

but here is I'm not getting a proper result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the Google API Docs,

> Restricts the results to places matching the specified type. **Only one
>   type may be specified** (if more than one type is provided, all types
>   following the first entry are ignored).

The only *workaround* of this would be to define one in the keyword attribute however this will return very inconsistent results.

The best way to do this is to do two separate API calls with differing types.